# How to re-write these multiple IF XML comparisons and loops in Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, foreach

This works, but I really don't like it and I'm pretty sure there is a better way of performing the comparisons using Linq. Can anyone help..

```
foreach (XElement xe in Tests)
{
    // hostname check
    string hostStarts = (string)xe.Element("hostStarts");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hostStarts) && !hostname.StartStartsith(hostStarts)) {  continue; }
    string hostContains = (string)xe.Element("hostContains");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hostContains) && !hostname.Contains(hostContains)) {  continue; }
    string hostEnds = (string)xe.Element("hostEnds");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hostEnds) && !hostname.EndStartsith(hostEnds)) {  continue; }

    // path checks
    string pathStarts = (string)xe.Element("pathStarts");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathStarts) && !pathname.StartStartsith(pathStarts)) {  continue; }
    string pathContains = (string)xe.Element("pathContains");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathContains) && !pathname.Contains(pathContains)) {  continue; }
    string pathEnds = (string)xe.Element("pathEnds");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathEnds) && !pathname.EndStartsith(pathEnds)) {  continue; }
    string pathEquals = (string)xe.Element("pathEquals");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathEquals) && !pathname.Equals(pathEquals)) {  continue; }


    // if we get to here then we want to perform some more stuff

}
```

I've seen the Linq method of 'bulk' comparison of all XML children before where no looping was required, but I'm not sure what it was called so am having little luck finding it.

Comment: There might be other SE sites suitable for this question.  SO is generally for when you have a problem, not code review

Answer (score 0):

What could work is to put the strings into a dictionary and map those strings to their corresponding operations, and perform those.

Something similar to this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

delegate bool delType(string str);

Dictionary<string, delType> pairs = new Dictionary<string, delType> {
    { "hostStarts", hostname.StartStartsith },
    { "hostContains" hostname.Contains },
    ...
    { "pathStarts", pathname.StartStartsith },
    ...
};

foreach (XElement xe in Tests)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, delType> pair in pairs)
    {
        string str = (string)xe.Element(pair.Key);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && !pair.Value(str))
            continue;
    }
}
```

(I recommend to change the variable names as you please.)

However, this assumes that the methods `Contains`, `StartStartsith`, and `EndStartsith` all have the same prototype.

I'd prefer this method because it clearly divides data from code. Adding some data is easy and it is all neatly split up.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have been looking into using Linq for the comparison but can't quite get my head around it. 

It seems like its possible to do a comparison of all descendants without the need for a foreach?

Comment: @JamesNapier I have no experience with LINQ, but I'm pretty sure it is possible.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, I've now added LINQ to my question as I think it will be a lot cleaner if I can work out how.